# jQuery ajax post authentication failing then succeeding

Tags: jquery, authentication

I have a very simple ajax call out to an internal web application that is giving me an issue:

`var service_url = *redacted*`

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: service_url,
            data: "kv:300929^3000AD INC^|",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (xml) { alert(xml); }
        });`
```

In Firebug, I see one ajax request get sent out and it comes back with a 401 response. So the success function never fires.

In Fiddler, I see something different. 4 calls go out to the other website. The first three return with 401 unauthorized. The 4th call comes back 200 OK. I look at the headers and the first call has no auth header. The next two have auth headers but are relatively short. And the last call has a very long auth header.

Attached is a screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/vylgg/5

The 4th call is giving me the information that I need to display, but I simply don't have access to that information from my current Javascript.

Comment: What exactly are you trying with your headers and why do you not have that information in JavaScript?

Comment: It looks like you may be sending a CORS request, but it also looks like it's same-origin. very odd.

Comment: I simply took out the hostname via MS Paint. It is making a call to a separate website.